# How windy does it have to be to cancel a cricket game?

Tags: cricket

How windy does it have to be to cancel a cricket game? What sort of wind speeds would make it impractical to play in?

Comment: Are you asking related to a particular league?  I imagine the "how windy" depends on the league, some will never cancel barring a thunderstorm/tornado, some might cancel more readily...

Comment: In general, high winds come attached to rain and/or dark, overcast skies (bad light) and it's one of those which cause play to be suspended rather than the wind itself.

Comment: I'm putting this on hold for the moment.  If you're able to clarify further what you're asking, either by explaining what league(s) you're asking about, or give more details to why you're asking, we can reopen, but as it currently is phrased there isn't really a direct answer.